# Erro no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli

estou tentando fazer com que toda vez que o usuário clicar em um botão aconteça um UPDATE, mas por algum motivo dá o `No database selected`, o que há de errado nesse código?

Update.PHP

```
<?php
 require_once 'Classes/BancoDAO.php';
 $codTarefa=$_GET['codTarefa'];

require_once "Classes/TarefasVO.php";
require_once "Classes/TarefasDAO.php";

 $objTarefa = new TarefasVO();
 $objBDTarefa = new TarefasDAO();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

$sqlDetalhes= "Select * from tarefas where codigo_TAREFA='$codTarefa'";
$rsDetalhes= mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlDetalhes) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

$tblDetalhes=mysqli_fetch_array($rsDetalhes);

$status=($tblDetalhes['status_TAREFA']+1);

 $objTarefa->setCodigoTarefa($codTarefa);
 $objTarefa->setStatusTarefa($status);

  $objBDTarefa->EditaStatusTarefa($codTarefa, $objTarefa);

  $codigo=$tblDetalhes['codidoAtividade_TAREFA'];

   header("location:Atividade.php?codAtividade=$codigo");


?>
```

TarefasDAO.phph -> função EditaStatusTarefa

```
  public function EditaStatusTarefa($codTarefa,$tmp){

  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

   $sqlEditaSN= "Update tarefas set status_TAREFA=";
$sqlEditaSN.="'".$tmp->getStatusTarefa()."'";
$sqlEditaSN.=" where codigo_TAREFA = '$codTarefa'";

mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlEditaSN) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$sqlDetalhes= "Select * from tarefas where codigo_TAREFA='$codTarefa'";
$rsDetalhes= mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlDetalhes) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

$tblDetalhes=mysqli_fetch_array($rsDetalhes);

$codigo=$tblDetalhes['codidoAtividade_TAREFA'];

header("location:Atividade.php?codAtividade=$codigo");

}
```

Comment: `$codigo=$tblDetalhes['codidoAtividade_TAREFA'];` altere para `$codigo=$tblDetalhes[0]['codidoAtividade_TAREFA'];`

Comment: Comente a linha `header("location:Atividade.php?codAtividade=$codigo");` e abaixo de `$sqlEditaSN` você cria essas linhas para testes: `echo $sqlEditaSN; die();` depois comente aqui o resultado que foi impresso na página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você nao está selecionando o banco de dados. A forma que você fez a conexão está orientada a objeto, porem a sua `query` está na forma procedural.

Altere essa linha:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');
```

Para:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');
```

Assim, a sua conexão com o banco estará também na forma procedural.

Comment: Você tem um erro de syntax do mysql, aparentemente sua variavel $codTarefa está vazia. Você pode testar sua query em qualquer workbench do mysql (por exemplo: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Outro teste que você pode fazer é substituir na linha:
$codTarefa=$_GET['codTarefa'];

Comment: @RodrigoSandrini Acho que o problena está nesta linha `$sqlEditaSN.="'".$tmp->getStatusTarefa()."',";`... Pois essa concatenaçao com uma virgula no final seguida de um WHERE vai dar erro

Comment: @J.Jones nao esquece de apagar esses `or die()` quando tudo estiver funcionando corretamente.

Comment: @J.Jones o problema pode estar no uso de "aspas". Esse `mysql_*` é o modo antigo de programar, se bem me lembro, os campos da tabela de valor numérico entre "aspas", tipo "1" ou "2", gera um erro de sintaxe. Altere essa linha para `$sqlDetalhes= "Select * from tarefas where codigo_TAREFA=$codTarefa";`